# How to create standalone executable when using subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, executable

I use subprocess to call a script(second_script.py) within another script(named first_script.py).
Is there a way of converting first_script.py into an executable without the further need of always having second_script.py in the same folder?

I use this line in first script to execute the second one:

```
out = subprocess.call(['python', 'second_script.py'])
```

And this line to convert it into exe but after the executable is created, requires always having second script in the same directory

```
pyinstaller --onefile first_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked in my case was to create an .exe for second script and replace the above line with

```
        def cmd(cmd: str = "ls -al", assertfail=True):
        up = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                              close_fds=False)
        str = [o.rstrip().decode() for o in up.stdout]
        exitcode = up.wait()
        return exitcode, str

    e, out = cmd("second_script.exe")
```

Then run

```
pyinstaller --onefile first_script.py
```

This way, even if I will have second_script.exe in same directory with first_script.exe, at least will run for others without the need of any libraries/packages to be installed.